# Ubuntu cannot be booted from external hard disk on another computer

Tags: installation, boot, 13.10, usb, external-hdd

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a external hard disk by using a Windows 8 laptop. I wanted it to be accessible from any other computers. But I found that there were 2 "Ubuntu"s at the boot manager screen even the external hard disk was not connected. Seems it is recognized as dual-boot. Later, I tried to boot it from another computer (Windows 7 desktop). The Ubuntu 13.10 inside cannot be loaded.

I can't find any other solutions, so I post it here. Hoping somebody can help me out.
P/S: Both the partition and the swap area are set as Primary Drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Ubuntu on the external HD your bootloader has probably been replaced with Grub and the Ubuntu entries where added. One of the entries boots Ubuntu (when HD is connected of course) in normal mode, the other entry start Ubuntu in rescue mode without graphical wrapper.

It's not suprising that Ubuntu won't load by default on an other computer. This bootloader doesn't know about Ubuntu on the external HD and therefore Ubuntu won't show up as option during boot. Now your system boots from (internal) HD. You can boot Ubuntu when you give your external HD a higher boot priority than your internal HD. You can set this in your BIOS.